# Limitar resultados en Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, api, djangorestframework

¿De qué manera se puede limitar los resultados de una consulta en DRF sin usar la paginación? Es decir, pasar a la URL el número de resultados que quiero obtener. Algo así:

```
https://www.example.com/api/v1/products/10
https://www.example.com/api/v1/products/20
https://www.example.com/api/v1/products/50
https://www.example.com/api/v1/products/100
```

Siendo el último valor el número de resultados que quiero obtener.

Lo que tengo ahora es:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('v1/product/all/', ProductDetail.as_view(), name='product_list'),
]
```

view.py

```
class ProductDetail(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    Lista los productos del catalogo de la empresa
    """
    queryset = Product.objects.all()[:20]
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre algo como lo siguiente:
en tus urls.py, a tu path agrega que reciba un parámetro para la cantidad.

```
path('v1/product/all/<int:quantity>/', ProductDetail.as_view(), name='product_list'),
```

Y en tu views.py donde está tu ProductDetail, puedes sobrescribir el método de get_queryset, de esta manera:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    quantity = int(self.kwargs["quantity"])# aquí recibimos la cantidad que quieres ver de registros y que definimos en la url.

    return Product.objects.all()[:quantity] # Aquí devolvemos la consulta con el número de registro que se solicite.
```

Espero haber entedido tu problema y que te funcione.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente!! Muchas gracias 